# Error while inserting data : cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, oracle11g, pycharm

I need to insert data into customer table

```
cur.execute(''' 
CREATE TABLE customer (customerId varchar(20),customerName 
varchar(20),telephoneNo int,
                        addressId int, customerType varchar(20),
                        discount int, memCardType varchar(20))''')
class customer:
    def __init__(self,customername,telephonenumber,addressid):
        self.customername=customername
        self.telephonenumber=telephonenumber
        self.addressid=addressid
        id=4
        t='a'

        cur.execute("INSERT INTO customer VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7)", 
   (id,customername,telephonenumber,addressid,t,id,t))
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM customer")
        print(cur.fetchall())`
if(ch==1):
nm = input("name:")
tel = input("number:")
add = input("address")
customer(nm,tel,add)
```

Error: here choice is being stored in variable ch, and if ch is 1 the data are being asked by user and data is stored in the table

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

customer(nm,tel,add)
line 23, in __init__
cur.execute("INSERT INTO customer VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7)",(id,customername,telephonenumber,addressid,t,id,t))
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Comment: This is often because the values aren't in the right order, and you should include the column list in the insert statement to avoid issues like that. That doesn't *seem* to be the issue here, but do it anyway. What values are you actually entering at the prompts?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your error. Code is working for me (once the backtick after fetchall is removed)

Comment: Even after removing the backtick and including the column list the code still produces error:   cur.execute("INSERT INTO customer (customerId,customerName,telephoneNo, addressId, customerType , discount, memCardType) VALUES(id,customername,telephonenumber,addressid,t,id,t)")
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00984: column not allowed here.

Comment: The values clause should still have the bind placeholders...?

Comment: like how? can you elaborate? I didnt get it.

Comment: Exactly as you are in the question. You only add the list of column names *before* the `values` keyword. But this still doesn't appear to address the issue. You still haven't edited the question to show the values you supplying when prompted. (I'd guess you have a phone number with dashes or spaces, or a text address rather than an ID for that).